# Float function returning 1.#R

Tags: c, floating-point, return-value

Good morning everyone!

**I have a problem like this:** 15 - Make a recursive function that calculates the value of the S series described below for a value n>0 to be provided as a parameter for it.
[The serie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUrwS.png)

I developed the following solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float calculateSerie (float numerator, float sum) 
{
    if (numerator>=1) 
    {
        printf("1+square(%.2f)/%.2f + ", numerator, numerator);
        sum+=((1+pow(numerator, 2))/numerator);
        calculateSerie(--numerator, sum);
    }
    else 
    {
        //Just a preview of what should go to the main method
        printf("\nSum: %f\n", sum);
        return sum;
    }
}   

int main () 
{
    float n, result, sum=0;

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%f", &n);

    puts(""); //Just line a break

    result = calculateSerie(n, sum);

    printf("\nFor %.2f the serie value is %.2f\n", n, result);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the output of my program to an n = 3 (randomly chosen number) is as follows:
[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zogs.png)

I wonder what "1. # R" means and if there is any way to resolve

Comment: Your `if` block in `calculateSerie` doesn't `return` anything.  If you're not getting a compiler warning about this, you should turn warnings on/up.

Comment: Thank you very much, friend! I managed to solve my problem, very silly even, I use Visual Studio Code and he did not alert me, I confess that I am starting in recursion and I also thought it was not necessary, again, thank you!

Comment: regarding: `sum+=((1+pow(numerator, 2))/numerator);`  the syntax for `pow()` is: `double pow(double x, double y);` which is a good way to create problems suggest using: `float powf(float x, float y);`  Which matches your parameters.  However, even then the function signature states that it returns a `float`, but the 'true' side of the `if()` returns nothing

Comment: regarding: `float n, result, sum=0;`  the variable `sum` is a `float` but is being initialized with a `int`, Suggest: `float n, result, sum=0.0f;`

Comment: regarding the recursive call: `calculateSerie(--numerator, sum);`  decrementing a `int` is ok.  decrementing a `float` very IFFY.

Answer (score 0):

using the posted code,

with replacing `pow()` with `powf()`

then entering `3` results in the value: `7.83`

However, entering a larger value, like 100123 results in a seg fault event due to stack overflow.